# tab bar icons in an app overlapping the Tab text

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I've implemented some tab bar icons in an app, but they seem to be overlapping the Tab text.

[image: Icons and descriptions in Tabs]

What am I doing wrong? 
Here's some code:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("TeamsFragment").setIndicator("Teams",
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bar_icon_teams_2x)), BaseFragment.class, null);
}

public class BaseFragment extends SherlockFragment {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a layout manager like `MigLayout` - this way you will be able to state exactly how you want your icons/buttons to look and where they should go. You're going to run into lots of problems if you don't use some sort of Layoutmanager...

Start by looking here: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf